# Entering floats into a list without overwriting list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some code here meant to allow me to keep creating floats until I input 0 to have it stop (the 0 is then deleted). These floats are supposed to be entered into a list. The issue I'm having is that each time the while loop is run, the float_list is overwritten.

```
again = True
float_count = 1
while (again):
    float_list = [float(input("Float%d: " % i))for i in range(float_count, float_count + 1)]
    last_float = float_list[-1]
    if (last_float == 0):
        again = False
        del float_list[-1]
    else:
        float_count = float_count + 1
```

Is there any way to alter this code so all of the floats are entered into a list? Thanks!

Comment: Initialize `float_list` outside the `while` loop and use `float_list.extend` inside the loop.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list comprehension really isn't appropriate here. Much simpler:

```
float_count = 1
float_list = []
while True:
    val = input("Float%d: " % float_count)
    if val == '0':
        break
    float_list.append(float(val))  # call float(val) to convert from string to float
    float_count += 1
```

it might be more user friendly to not crash if the user didn't type a float, e.g.:

```
def read_float(msg):
    while 1:
        val = input(msg)
        if val == '0':
            return val
        try:
            return float(val)
        except ValueError:
            print("%s is not a float, please try again.." % val)

def read_float_list():
    float_count = 1
    float_list = []
    while True:
        val = read_float("Float%d: " % float_count)
        if val == '0':
            break
        float_list.append(val)  # now val has been converted to float by read_float.
        float_count += 1
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. For some reason, later in my code I get an error while using this. I'm using itertools to generate combinations from the list as seen below:
`for c in itertools.combinations(float_list, 10):
    average = sum(c)/10`
But I get: _average = sum(c)/10
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'_. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I think this is because the list is `['.1', '.2', '.3', '.4', '.5', '.6', '.7', '.8', '.9', '.8', '.7', '.6', '.5', '.5', '.5', '.6', '.7']` and before it was `[.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9, .8, .7, .6, .5, .5, .5, .6, .7]` Is there any way to make the list look like before?

Comment: sorry, I forgot that Python 3 changed the semantics of the `input` function. I've fixed the code.

Comment: I was able to figure that out :). Any idea on removing the apostrophes from the list?

Comment: Only saw the val == 0 being changed to val == '0'. You have helped me a lot, thanks mate!

Comment: When I run the code as seen here: https://repl.it/FY79 nothing happens, any Idea why?

Comment: Actually I got it! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

This maybe a good option to use the alternative form of `iter(fn, sentinel)`, e.g.:

```
float_list = [float(x) for x in iter(input, '0')]
```

If you need the prompt then you can create a helper function:

```
import itertools as it

fc = it.count(1)
float_list = [float(x) for x in iter(lambda: input('Float{}: '.format(next(fc))), '0')]
```

Or alternatively (most closely matches OP's attempt - would exit on `0`, `0.0`, `0.00`, etc.):

```
fc = it.count(1)
float_list = list(iter(lambda: float(input('Float{}: '.format(next(fc)))), 0.0))
```

With error handling:

```
def get_float():
    fc = it.count(1)
    def _inner():
        n = next(fc)
        while True:
            try:
                return float(input("Float{}: ".format(n)))
            except ValueError as e:
                print(e)
    return _inner

float_list = list(iter(get_float(), 0.0))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Will you be able to add `0.` (the float value zero) to the list?

Comment: @thebjorn In the first 2 snippets yes, in the last 2 no, but simple enough to add that handling if necessary. Wasn't something explicitly asked for by the OP, and the OPs original code would stop on `'0.'` too.

Comment: Fair enough, and I'll give you a point for an out-of-the-box solution (way out of the box ;-)